# Error running any Composer command

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, composer

I am working on a project with multiple developers and another member of the team is getting on with a Plugin to assist with some CraftCommerce integrations.

As it's not a publicly available plugin, it's being stored locally in our repo.

However, whenever I run any Composer command on my local machine I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
  Package <agency>/<plugin> cannot install to
  "/Users/jaycollett/Development/project/build/custom/<plugin>"
  inside its source at "/Users/jaycollett/Development/project/build/
  custom/<plugin>"
```

We have found this response from Andrew Welch, but it can't be this because our Composer.json repositories section is as follows:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "./custom/<plugin>"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it with the team we worked out that deleting the plugin directory from the `/vendors` folder and rerunning `composer install` resolved it. Not sure why though...